# How to add dependency between two release pipeline Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a scenario that i want to create a dependency in Release pipelines that once one pipeline completes its task then the next release pipeline should be triggered.
How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add dependency between two release pipeline Azure DevOps

You could use the extension [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline):

> Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline is an extension for triggering a Azure
> DevOps Build or Release Pipeline.
>
> Depending on your choice in the task, it will trigger a build or a
> release pipeline.
>
> To use the extension, an Azure DevOps API endpoint needs to be
> created. The token used in the endpoint should be Personal Access
> Token.